# After typing php artisan serve, encounter error when trying to reach 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: php, laravel, iis, laravel-artisan

I'm using IIS as web server,
after I ran php artisan serve on the terminal,

I encountered error when trying to reach 127.0.0.1:8000.

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or 
directory in Unknown  on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed 
opening  required 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel/server.php'
 (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried to look for other answers here, but none of them seems to work.

Any idea what went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of the Laravel's community uses open-sourced webservers (NGINX, Apache) you may find it difficult to fine-tune IIS, because of lack of community created content on setting up IIS. This comment is just heads-up.

Comment: Thankyou for the heads up

Comment: so just curious are you suggesting that laravel is relatively not compatible with IIS

Comment: I have never worked with IIS myself, so I am not sure. You may want to read this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/iis7-laravel-5. Using open-sourced web-servers makes live easier since many people write up blogs, guides... about setting up "server" with Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming cause in your working repository `server.php` file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Oops forgot to update .I've downloaded the laravel 5.4,It turns out I forgot to include the .dev file, it works now